# GetFileSize method fails on file of exactly 146170227 bytes

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, ftp

Yeah, this is a weird one.

When attempting to get the file size of a file on an FTP server in Windows Server 2003(SP1 and 2), the action will fail if the file size is EXACTLY 146170227 bytes. Seriously. One byte more or less and it works.

More specifically, it will fail by replying

'213 14617022_'

rather than:

'213 146170227'

Of course, in any programming language this will cause an error, since that's not a number.

(I've managed to duplicate this in Python and .NET, and have seen the actual packet with faulty data going through in Wireshark, hence the reason the question is here rather in Stackoverflow)

Has anyone run into this in the past? Any ideas what it might be?

Answer (score 3):

I would say: Send a bug report to MS.

Comment: +1 to send bug report.